# Why do I get the 'Oops' error from Instagram API location search (when using coordinates)?

Tags: api, foursquare, instagram

I'm tring to search locations with the Instagram API in my application but also when testing with Apigee, I get `500 Internal server error`, and `Oops, an error occurred.`

Apigee: https://apigee.com/console/instagram

Authenticate yourself and add this URL: https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=40.758896&lng=-73.985131

It should return Time Square locations. It worked a few times in the past, but currently it doesn't.

It would be an overkill to use the Foursquare api to search for locations, then pass the location id to Instagram. Is that the only way to get around this? Because once you know the location's ID it works ok.

My possible solution would be to let the user find the desired location here: http://worldc.am/id/47383924f964a520444c1fe3
And use the v2 foursquare API location ID for Instagram.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. The strange part is that there's a range of distances for which the Oops message is received (358-1052 in my case) but values outside that range (higher OR lower) work fine. Instagram, please fix this!

Comment: My proposed possible solution worked in the end. The key is to find the location somehow other than a search by Instagram API, then use the (foursquare) location ID as you would use your search result ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Instagram API is pretty bad in that regards - it often just says "Oops an error occured!", without giving you any more info.

I believe their servers have a really low time out limit. Add the parameter distance=500, or even less, and you won't get this error any more. Basically, in a high density area (like a big city), you need to specify a small distance number, otherwise Instagram's server just times out while serving your request.